# ps is not showing all processes

Tags: ubuntu, scripting, process, ps

I used the `script` command immediately after I started the terminal, it started recording my current session but when i used `ps` command after that it is showing only two processes, one for `bash` and one for `ps` itself but it is not showing any process for the script command that is running in the background, why is it so? Speaking in a more general way actually I have never seen the `ps` command showing more than 2 processes on my terminal, is there something wrong with my shell or terminal settings? I am currently using Ubuntu.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with your terminal or your shell. By default, `ps` shows processes with the same effective user identifier as the user running it, and associated with the same terminal. This typically results in only two processes showing up: the current shell, and `ps` itself. If there are any background processes associated with the current terminal, they will show up too; you can see this by running

```
sleep 120 &
ps
```

To see all processes, run

```
ps -e
```

There are a number of other process selection flags, see `man ps` on your system for details.

When you run `script`, it allocates a new terminal and starts a new shell; so `ps` inside `script` is running on a different terminal (even though it’s in the same terminal *window* on your system, or on the same virtual console). That’s why you don’t see `script`. You can see this happen by running `tty` before and after running `script`: you’ll see it output two different values.

See also [What is the exact difference between a 'terminal', a 'shell', a 'tty' and a 'console'?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/4126/86440)