# nohup ends when I close the SSH terminal and doesn't show up on ps/job when running

Tags: ssh, process, amazon-ec2, nohup, mpi

I have an AWS EC2 Ubuntu 20.04 instance, accessed via puTTY SSH. Running a Python process via [OpenMPI](https://www.open-mpi.org/) through the following command **on non root**:

> nohup mpirun python3 job.py

When the shell is open it runs normally. Even though using `ps` and `job` doesn't show the process I can see via the nohup.out and the changing file system that it's working even hours after it runs.

When I close the shell the nohup process ends. I should probably also note that when I run the nohup command above I cannot enter any more input (the cursor becomes blank). So when I ran `ps` and `job` above I had to open a second shell. I never used nohup before and assume this is abnormal.

I investigated the nohup.out file for errors and found nothing written.

So TLDR:

1. Closing the SSH instance (puTTY) ends the nohup process
2. ps and job don't list the nohup process even though I know it's running

*I can answer any more questions if needed*

Comment: can you edit python script `job.py` ? if yes, you can run it in background, close stdin, stdout and stderr (altough I never did it on ec2 instance), then you can close ssh connection.

Comment: @Archemar I can edit job.py but what do you mean by that?

Comment: use `sys.stdin.close()` (and stdout and stderr) before calling `pid=os.fork()` exit when pid > 0. be sure to check that mpi layer do not use standard I/O (that wasn't obvious in `mpirun` man page.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`jobs` can only show you jobs of the current shell.

Bare `ps` [shows processes with the same effective user ID as the current user and the same controlling terminal as the invoker](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/489733/108618). You need e.g. `ps -e` to see other processes ([not necessarily all processes in the OS though](https://superuser.com/a/704035/432690)).

If you run

```
nohup something … &
```

then you will be able to run `jobs` or `ps` in the same shell. Don't expect to see `nohup`. Its task is to run `something` in a specific way, it doesn't need to last. Expect to see `something`.

So it may be your process survived and you only assumed it had died. Or it may be it really died. See [*Why was process killed with `nohup`?*](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/420594/108618) The [answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/420663/108618) there mentions two possibilities:

- `KillUserProcesses=yes` in `logind.conf` (systemd);
- or the spawned process implements its own handler for `SIGHUP` which overrides the protection of `nohup`.

More here: [*Difference between `nohup`, `disown` and `&`*](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/3886/108618). If I understand correctly, `disown` can help if the spawned process implements its own handler for `SIGHUP`. Use it like this:

```
nohup something … &
disown
```